# locationManagerDidUpdateLocation

Tags: swift, core-location

I have a delegate class as per below:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

protocol LocationManagerDelegate: class {
    func locationManagerDidUpdateLocation(_ locationManager: LocationManager, location: CLLocation)
    func locationManagerDidUpdateHeading(_ locationManager: LocationManager, heading: CLLocationDirection, accuracy: CLLocationDirection)
}

///Handles retrieving the location and heading from CoreLocation
class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    weak var delegate: LocationManagerDelegate?

    private var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

    var currentLocation: CLLocation?

    var heading: CLLocationDirection?
    var headingAccuracy: CLLocationDegrees?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        self.locationManager!.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        self.locationManager!.headingFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone
        self.locationManager!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        self.locationManager!.delegate = self
        self.locationManager!.startUpdatingHeading()
        self.locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()

        self.locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        self.currentLocation = self.locationManager!.location
    }

    func requestAuthorization() {
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways ||
            CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse {
            return
        }

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.denied ||
            CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.restricted {
            return
        }

        self.locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    //MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        for location in locations {
            self.delegate?.locationManagerDidUpdateLocation(self, location: location)
        }

        self.currentLocation = manager.location
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        if newHeading.headingAccuracy >= 0 {
            self.heading = newHeading.trueHeading
        } else {
            self.heading = newHeading.magneticHeading
        }

        self.headingAccuracy = newHeading.headingAccuracy

        self.delegate?.locationManagerDidUpdateHeading(self, heading: self.heading!, accuracy: newHeading.headingAccuracy)
    }

    func locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration(_ manager: CLLocationManager) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Now from another class, which is UIViewController I want to make some tasks based upon when the location changes (locationManagerDidUpdateLocation). I want to do this not extending my VC, but using the previous class. How can I achieve this?
...........................

Thanks.

Comment: `didUpdateLocations` gets called a lot, even when the location isn't ostensibly changing because the delegate is trying to get its most accurate coordinate. Do you want the task to be called only once when the location first becomes available, repeatedly for each location update even if it basically gives you the same coordinate, or only when the coordinate has significantly changed?

Comment: what i want is to have just 1 delegate and from the other classes access didUpdateLocations.

Comment: You can post a notification from within the `didUpdateLocations` method and place notification observers in the objects that have the methods (tasks) you want called. If you also want to grant those objects access to the location coordinates, since `didUpdateLocations` returns an array of `CLLocation` data, create an instance property in `LocationManager` and simply update that property from within `didUpdateLocations`. You can then make `LocationManager` a singleton which would then make that location data (that instance property) available from any object in the app.